# Check if List<T> element contains an item with a Particular Property Value

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class Item
{
    public List<int> val { get; set; }
    public double support { get; set; }
}
```

I declare variable:

```
List<Item> t = new List<Item>();
t.Add(new Item(){val = new List<int>(){1,2,3};support=.1);
var b = new Item();
b.val = t[0].val;
b.support=t[0].support;
t.Contain(b) // return false???
```

I'm try with linq

```
t.Any(a=>a.val==b.val) // I'm get error Expression cannot contain lambda expressions
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 possibilities come to mind:

You could implement [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx):

```
public class Item: IEquatable<Item>
{
    public List<int> val { get; set; }
    public double support { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Item other)
    {
        return
            this.support == other.support &&
            this.val.SequenceEqual(other.val);
    }
}
```

and now `t.Contains(b)` will return true.

---

If you cannot modify the `Item` class you could write a custom [EqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132123.aspx):

```
public class ItemEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Item>
{
    private ItemEqualityComparer()
    {
    }

    public static IEqualityComparer<Item> Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return new ItemEqualityComparer();
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(Item x, Item y)
    {
        return
            x.support == y.support &&
            x.val.SequenceEqual(y.val);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Item obj)
    {
        int hash = 27;
        hash += (13 * hash) + obj.support.GetHashCode();
        foreach (var item in obj.val)
        {
            hash += (13 * hash) + item.GetHashCode();
        }
        return hash;
    }
}
```

and then `t.Contains(b)` will also return `true`.

---

Or if you prefer simply do it naively:

```
List<Item> t = new List<Item>();
t.Add(new Item { val = new List<int>(){1,2,3}, support=.1 });

var b = new Item();
b.val = t[0].val;
b.support = t[0].support;

bool equals = t.All(item => item.support == b.support && item.val.SequenceEqual(b.val));
Console.WriteLine(equals);
```

Comment: tks, it's help me. You can explain why t.Any(a=>a.val==b.val) // I'm get error Expression cannot contain lambda expressions

Comment: You shouldn't be getting this error. I am not sure why this might happen as the code sample you have provided in your question is invalid C# and doesn't compile. For example your object initializer is wrong. You have a missing closing `}` and used `;` instead of `,` to separate proeprty names.

Comment: Oh, this code is sample, and i confusion ',' to ';', In window watch(debug) i get error Expression cannot contain lambda expressions for t.Any(a=>a.val==b.val). Sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

Your `t.Any(a=>a.val == b.val)` is correct.

The error you get is from the quick watch or expression window in the debugger, not from the compiler. Visual Studio's expression evaluator does not handle lambdas.  However, it's still valid c# code, and will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It's your earlier line that's a problem:

```
t.Add(new Item(){val = new List<int>(){1,2,3};support=.1);
```

This is a mixture of various different bits of syntax. It should be:

```
t.Add(new Item(){val = new List<int>(){1,2,3}, support=.1});
```

... although preferably with better property names, etc. Then the rest should work - although you need to do something with the result of `Any`. The `Any` call itself is valid. Here's a short but complete program which works:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Item
{
    public List<int> Values { get; set; }
    public double Support { get; set; }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<Item> list = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item { Values = new List<int>{1, 2, 3},
                       Support = 0.1 }
        };

        var check = new Item { Values = list[0].Values,
                               Support = list[0].Support };

        bool found = list.Any(a => a.Values == check.Values);
        Console.WriteLine(found);
    }
}
```

Note that this is performing a *reference* comparison between the two lists - if you created a different list with the same values (1, 2, 3), that wouldn't be found. You'd need to use `a.Values.SequenceEqual(b.Values)` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Item` class should implemenet the `IEquatable` interface:

```
class Item : IEquatable<Item>{
    public List<int> val { get; set; }
    public double support { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Item item){
       return this.support.Equals(item.support) && this.val.SequenceEqual(item.val);          
    }
}
```

Then the `Contains()` method should work well.

Answer (score 0):

You can correct your 
"`t.Contain(b)`" 
to
 `t.Contains(b, new ItemEqualityComparer())` from `System.Linq` 
where `ItemEqualityComparer` will be your class, which will implement `IEqualityComparer<Item>`